# JFrog Artifactory failed to initialize with error 500

Tags: artifactory

Installed Artifactory on centos VM using open source rpm package but it fails to initialize.

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Artifactory failed to initialize: check Artifactory logs for errors."
  } ]
}
```

**Tried adding below in system.yaml file:**

```
shared:
    node:
        ip: <your ipv4 IP>
```

**Post checking console logs says below error:**

```
Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2021-01-05T10:36:18.597Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [f61fe454765979f3] [ctoryContextConfigListener:126] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:265)
        at org.artifactory.lifecycle.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.initReloadableBeans(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:302)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:284)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:174)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy184.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.initReloadableBeans(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:300)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Cluster join: Service registry ping failed; Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessServerStartupValidator.waitForServer(AccessServerStartupValidator.java:39)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.waitForServer(AccessClientBootstrap.java:149)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.<init>(AccessClientBootstrap.java:104)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientBootstrap.<init>(AccessClientBootstrap.java:134)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1290)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.lambda$bootstrapAccessClient$23(AccessServiceImpl.java:1251)
        at io.vavr.control.Try.mapTry(Try.java:634)
        at io.vavr.control.Try.map(Try.java:585)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.bootstrapAccessClient(AccessServiceImpl.java:1251)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessService(AccessServiceImpl.java:421)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.initAccessClientIfNeeded(AccessServiceImpl.java:410)
        at org.artifactory.security.access.AccessServiceImpl.init(AccessServiceImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.artifactory.storage.fs.lock.aop.LockingAdvice.invoke(LockingAdvice.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.common.ExecutionFailed: Cluster join: Service registry ping failed; Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleStopError(ExecutionUtils.java:156)
        at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleFunctionExecution(ExecutionUtils.java:103)
        at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.lambda$generateExecutionRunnable$0(ExecutionUtils.java:67)
        at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils$MDCRunnableDecorator.run(ExecutionUtils.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.jfrog.common.RetryException: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessServerStartupValidator.convertToRetryException(AccessServerStartupValidator.java:56)
        at io.vavr.API$Match$Case0.apply(API.java:5135)
        at io.vavr.API$Match.option(API.java:5105)
        at io.vavr.control.Try.mapFailure(Try.java:602)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessServerStartupValidator.pingAccess(AccessServerStartupValidator.java:46)
        at org.jfrog.common.ExecutionUtils.handleFunctionExecution(ExecutionUtils.java:100)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientException: Unable to connect to Access server: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:143)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.ping(AccessHttpClient.java:114)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessClientImpl.ping(AccessClientImpl.java:252)
        at io.vavr.control.Try.run(Try.java:118)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.AccessServerStartupValidator.pingAccess(AccessServerStartupValidator.java:45)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.jfrog.client.http.CloseableHttpClientDecorator.doExecute(CloseableHttpClientDecorator.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
        at org.jfrog.access.client.http.AccessHttpClient.restCall(AccessHttpClient.java:130)
        ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
2021-01-05T10:36:19.367Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryFilter:213 ] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Artifactory failed to initialize: Context is null
2021-01-05T10:36:21.058Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [f455f35e70ecf56 ] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:142      ] [pool-23-thread-2    ] - Retry 180 Elapsed 1.52 minutes failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
^C
```

Below is the snippet of router.log:

```
_2021-01-05T10:34:55.424Z [jfrou] [FATAL] [112e7162aa72477c] [bootstrap.go:101              ] [main                ] - Could not join access, err: Cluster join: Failed joining the cluster; Error: Error response from service registry, status code: 400; message: Could not validate router Check-url: http://108.167.159.189:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping; detail: I/O error on GET request for "http://108.167.159.189:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping": Connect to 108.167.159.189:8082 [/108.167.159.189] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 108.167.159.189:8082 [/108.167.159.189] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2021-01-05T11:05:29.439Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [bootstrap.go:72               ] [main                ] - Router (jfrou) service initialization started. Version: 7.12.4-1 Revision: 5060ba45bc3229a899aee49cb87d680398ab017f PID: 20257 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2021-01-05T11:05:29.440Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [bootstrap.go:75               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router IP: 108.167.159.189
2021-01-05T11:05:29.441Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [bootstrap.go:175              ] [main                ] - System configuration encryption report:
shared.newrelic.licenseKey: does not exist in the config file
shared.security.joinKeyFile: file '/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key' - already encrypted
2021-01-05T11:05:29.442Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [bootstrap.go:80               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router Service ID: jfrou@01ev5km60hpft7szeaf1n24e48
2021-01-05T11:05:29.442Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [bootstrap.go:81               ] [main                ] - JFrog Router Node ID: osboxes.org
2021-01-05T11:05:29.476Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [http_client_holder.go:155     ] [main                ] - System cert pool contents were loaded as trusted CAs for TLS communication
2021-01-05T11:05:29.476Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [http_client_holder.go:175     ] [main                ] - Following certificates were successfully loaded as trusted CAs for TLS communication:
[/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/router/keys/trusted/access-root-ca.crt]
2021-01-05T11:05:31.486Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [config_holder.go:107          ] [main                ] - Configuration update detected
2021-01-05T11:05:31.780Z [jfrou] [INFO ] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [join_executor.go:118          ] [main                ] - Cluster join: Trying to rejoin the cluster
2021-01-05T11:05:32.629Z [jfrou] [FATAL] [d21e36b02d1a444 ] [bootstrap.go:101              ] [main                ] - Could not join access, err: Cluster join: Failed joining the cluster; Error: Error response from service registry, status code: 400; message: Could not validate router Check-url: http://108.167.159.189:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping; detail: I/O error on GET request for "http://108.167.159.189:8082/router/api/v1/system/ping": Connect to 108.167.159.189:8082 [/108.167.159.189] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 108.167.159.189:8082 [/108.167.159.189] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)_
```

Comment: post logs of router and results of systemdiagnostics from the app/bin directory

Comment: @HumayunM - Added router.log snippet in original post.

Comment: Also below is the Linux version:
Linux osboxes.org 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 18 16:34:56 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What java version you are using?